# Is it possible to update a DataTemplate in code?

Tags: c#, uwp, datatemplate

Is there a way to update a DataTemplate in code?

I have a simple DataTemplate containing a single image. It's used for a 3rd party control's ContentTemplate property to represent the control's viewable image.  (I have no control over this requirement.)  Here's the DataTemplate's XAML definition with a generic "unknown" image:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ControlImageDataTemplate">
        <Image Source="Assets/UnknownImage.png"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

In my app, different control instances can have different images, and I don't know which image to use until run-time.  So I need to update the DataTemplate image source at run-time in the code-behind.  Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
    // Update the DataTemplate
    ControlImageDataTemplate.Image.Source = new BitmapImage("Assets/RunTimeImage.png"); // CAN'T DO THIS!!!

    // Assign the updated DataTemplate to the control instance
    ThirdPartyControl.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["ControlImageDataTemplate"];
```

However, I have not been able to find a way to update a DataTemplate in code.  Is this possible?  Or is there an alternative?

Comment: Can you use a `DataTemplateSelector`?

Comment: Have you tried @Raymond Chen's suggestion to use `DataTemplateSelector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users suggested in the comments, the perfect way to do this is with a `DataTemplateSelector`.

First of all, you need to derive the `DataTemplateSelector` class, creating your own, and overriding the `SelectTemplateCore` method:

```
public class SampleDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null && container != null && <<item is a specific object>>)
        {
            // Put your logic code here in order to determine what case is the right one
            if (<<case 1>>) return SampleDataTemplate1;
            else if (<<case 2>>) return SampleDataTemplate2;
            //…
        }
    }
}
```

Then, put theese resources in your App.xaml (or into your Page's resources):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <templateSelectorNamespace:SampleDataTemplateSelector x:Key="SampleTemplateSelector"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate1">
        <Image Source="Assets/Image1.png"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SampleDataTemplate2">
        <Image Source="Assets/Image2.png"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, into your page, just use it with an ItemsControl derived control.
Here's a way to use it, for example, in a ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Elements, Mode=OneWay}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SampleTemplateSelector}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Best regards